# Visual C++ errors C3867 and C2664

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

```
#define UCHAR unsigned char

typedef bool (*FUNC)(UCHAR uc1, UCHAR uc2);
typedef void(*PF)(FUNC, UCHAR*);
PF    Assign;

class Class  {
    private:
       UCHAR buf[32];
       bool func(UCHAR c1, UCHAR c2)  { }

    public:
       Class::Class(void)  {
          Assign( func, buf );         // <<< Microsoft VC++ error C3867
       }

       Class::~Class()  { }
};
```

> error C3867: 'Class::func': function call missing argument list;
>   use '&Class::func' to create a pointer to member

If I try the suggestion in the error message above

> Assign( &Class::func, buf );         // <<< Microsoft VC++ error C2664

I get this error:

> error C2664: 'void (FUNC,unsigned char *)' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'bool (__thiscall Class::* )(unsigned char,unsigned char)'
>   to 'FUNC'
>   There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Without changing anything else how can I get this Assign() function to compile?
These typedefs are from a library that I need to interface with.

Comment: Never do this: `#define UCHAR unsigned char` - always use a typedef, e.g. `typedef unsigned char UCHAR;`

Answer (score 1):

`func` is a non-static member function, so its type is `bool (Class::*)(UCHAR, UCHAR)`, while `Assign` requires `bool (*)(UCHAR, UCHAR)`. You cannot convert a non-static member function to a non-member function.

To be able to pass `func` into `Assign`, you'll have to make `func` static.

Answer (score 1):

The type-aliases `FUNC` and `PF` are not a member function pointers, and can only be used to point to *static* member functions. The reason being that all non-static member functions have an implicit first argument for the `this` pointer.

If you need generic function "pointers" you should look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
typedef std::function<bool(UCHAR uc1, UCHAR uc2)> FUNC;
typedef std::function<void(FUNC, UCHAR*)> PF;
PF    Assign;

Class::Class(void)  {
    Assign( std::bind(&Class::func, *this), buf );
}
```

Comment: But I can't modify the 3rd part library typedefs and the PF Assign; line. If I make func static then I can't access class variables. I get this error: error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Class::buf'

Comment: @user292344 If the `FUNC` and `PF` types are part of a third-party library, you should state so in the question. If this is the case, then you need to rethink your design.